# How to change boolean value in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am writing a program using html/php/javascript. The purpose of the program is to have a list of jobs for a person to do (these jobs are stored in a database). When they complete a job they can click a button so the job with be changed to done (or true). There is no user input just a button for the user to click to mark the job as finished. The question is how do I change the value in the "Done" column in the database when the button is clicked for the specific job?

```
<html>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Business Name</th>
            <th> Address </th>
            <th> Done </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname ="myDB";

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "Select * from jobs where done = '1'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            $businessname = $row['Business'];



        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Business']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Done']; ?> </td>
            <td> <button type = 'submit' name = 'Done' value = '{businessname}' >Accept</button></td>
        </tr>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>    
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe `update jobs set done = 1 where id = ?`? or are you asking how to send an AJAX request? I dont know where you are hung up

Comment: I hung up on changing the value of the Boolean in the database when the user clicks the button.

Comment: There are multiple steps there though.Currently you just have a `button` which will do nothing. You could make a form that submits to a PHP processing page and updates your DB, or you could have a listener in JS that fires an AJAX event to a PHP processor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_POST['Done']){

global $conn;

$done = trim($_POST["Done"]);

$job_id = trim($_POST["job_id"]);

$query = "UPDATE jobs SET done='$done' WHERE business = $job_id";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error($conn->error."[ DB ]");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
        $_SESSION['answer'] = "<div class='success'>Updated!</div>";
        return true;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['edit_page']['res'] = "<div class='error'>Error!</div>";
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injections. The OP should not try this. Also `global` doesn't make sense unless it is being used in a function. OP and this answer are both using procedural code.